# If error is not nil why return both err and nil?

Tags: go, return-value

I'm following [golang wiki instruction](https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/) and find this confusing:

```
func loadPage(title string) (*Page, error) {
    filename := title + ".txt"
    body, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return &Page{Title: title, Body: body}, nil
}
```

If err not equal nil, why return nil?

Isn't it supposed to be:

```
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

like it is described in [golang errors and values](https://blog.golang.org/errors-are-values)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In loadpage function you are returning two values, one is a pointer to Page and other is an error.

```
func loadPage(title string) (*Page, error) {
    filename := title + ".txt"
    body, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return &Page{Title: title, Body: body}, nil
}
```

That's the reason if there is an error in the code and it is not equal to nil. Then return the error. But since you need to return Page also it should be nil since which denotes zero value for pointer. This shows that the value for Page is empty.

```
return &Page{Title: title, Body: body}, nil
```

But if there is no error then again you are returning two values one is the address of Page struct with values assigned to the Page fields but nil for error.

If a value of a type does not contains any value. It should be initialize with zero value which is

> false for booleans, 0 for numeric types, "" for strings, and nil for
>   pointers, functions, interfaces, slices, channels, and maps.

The return value or values may be explicitly listed in the "return" statement. Each expression must be single-valued and assignable to the corresponding element of the function's result type.

```
func complexF1() (re float64, im float64) {
    return -7.0, -4.0
}
```

The expression list in the "return" statement may be a single call to a multi-valued function. The effect is as if each value returned from that function were assigned to a temporary variable with the type of the respective value, followed by a "return" statement listing these variables, at which point the rules of the previous case apply.

```
func complexF2() (re float64, im float64) {
    return complexF1()
}
```

**Note:**

> Regardless of how they are declared, all the result values are
>   initialized to the zero values for their type upon entry to the
>   function. A "return" statement that specifies results sets the result
>   parameters before any deferred functions are executed.

Have a look on Golang spec for [Return statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Return_statements)

Comment: Thanks @Himanshu, so if there's error, I return all the vars the function supposed to return. 

The way I see it is: 

`if (err) throw err else return (vars supposed to return)`.

So in Go, the line after the `if` statement is not an `else`?

Comment: @Viet Actually It is like returning multiple values. you can set as many values as you want. But suppose if there is an error the you should return the error and set zero value for other variables. I have mentioned in my answer what values you should return as zero values for different types.

Answer (score 6):

The function returns 2 things: A Page (pointer) and an error. If an error occurs, there is no page to be returned, hence the first value returned is `nil`. The second value being returned is the error, `err`, as it should.

Comment: Thanks @Leon. So if the function returns x things, for every if statement, I should return x vars?

Comment: Yes, whenever you `return` from a function, you must return all values the function returns.

Answer (score 2):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [The zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value)
>
> When storage is allocated for a variable, either through a declaration
>   or a call of new, or when a new value is created, either through a
>   composite literal or a call of make, and no explicit initialization is
>   provided, the variable or value is given a default value. Each element
>   of such a variable or value is set to the zero value for its type:
>   false for booleans, 0 for numeric types, "" for strings, and nil for
>   pointers, functions, interfaces, slices, channels, and maps. This
>   initialization is done recursively, so for instance each element of an
>   array of structs will have its fields zeroed if no value is specified.

---

Because of the error, there is no valid value to return so we return the zero value, which happens to be `nil` (for a pointer value) in this case.